# Laravel Vuejs Pusher Issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport, pusher

Project details:

- Laravel 9 with Laravel Passport for API
- Users authenticate to `/admins/` API endpoint using the AWS Cognito ID token (Bearer token)
- Vuejs 2 with VuePusher package

I have Laravel job in the project which creates time slots for a schedule. When the time slots are created I invoke the following in the job:

`broadcast(new TimeSlotsCreated($schedule));`

The `TimeSlotsCreated` event looks like this:

```
class TimeSlotsCreated implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable,
        InteractsWithSockets,
        SerializesModels;
    
    /** @var Schedule */
    public $schedule;

    public function __construct(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $this->schedule = $schedule;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {        
        return new PrivateChannel('admin-activity');
    }
    
    public function broadcastAs(): string
    {        
        return 'time-slots-created';
    }
    
    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return ['schedule' => $this->schedule];
    }
}
```

- I have uncommented out the `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` in `config/app.php` file
- My `routes/channels.php` file looks like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('admin-activity', function () {
    return auth()->check();
}, ['guards' => ['admin-cognito']]);
```

In the `main.js` file (Vuejs 2) I have:

```
Vue.use(VuePusher, {
    api_key: process.env.VUE_APP_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    options: {
        cluster: process.env.VUE_APP_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
        encrypted: true,
        authEndpoint: process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL + '/api/broadcasting/auth',
        auth: {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer XYZ`
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In the vuejs component I have this in `mounted()` method:

```
this.$pusher.subscribe('private-admin-activity', channel => {
   channel.bind('time-slots-created', ({ schedule }) => {
       console.log(schedule)
   })
})
```

But the `console.log` never gets triggered.

I have defined all pusher vars in `.env` file. I don't understand why request to `/api/broadcasting/auth` would trigger a request to 'login' route. I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/js-dojo/laravel-passport-pusher-vue-js-27fcec38546b

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get this to work but with public channel.